# Dynamically loading RadTabStrip tabs with usercontrols not showing

Tags: tabs, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with a NestedViewTemplate that has a RadTabStrip in it.  What I am doing is loading UserControls(ascx) files into each tab that I have created in the RadMultiPage.  The tabs are static but the UserControls are loaded dynamically.  They are not showing up all the time.  Here is my main page that they are located on.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel">
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gdDocket" runat="server" ShowGroupPanel="True" GridLines="None"
    CellSpacing="0" ActiveItemStyle-BackColor="#0066FF" Width="1000" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True"
    OnInsertCommand="gdDocket_InsertCommand" OnNeedDataSource="gdDocket_NeedDataSource"
    OnUpdateCommand="gdDocket_UpdateCommand" OnItemCommand="gdDocket_ItemCommand"
    Skin="Web20" OnItemCreated="gdDocket_ItemCreated" 
    onitemdatabound="gdDocket_ItemDataBound">
    <ActiveItemStyle BackColor="#0066FF"></ActiveItemStyle>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
    <GroupHeaderItemStyle BackColor="SlateGray" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle Wrap="false" />
    <MasterTableView HierarchyDefaultExpanded="false" Width="100%" EditMode="PopUp" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1"
        CellSpacing="1" CommandItemDisplay="Top" GridLines="Both" DataKeyNames="claim_num,docket_id"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" GroupLoadMode="Server" >
        <NestedViewTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="InnerContainer" Visible="true">
                <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="TabStip1" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" 
                MultiPageID="Multipage1" SelectedIndex="0" ClickSelectedTab="True" OnTabClick="TabStrip1_TabClick">
                    <Tabs>
                        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Value="Full" Text="Full Claim" PageViewID="FullClaimPage">
                        </telerik:RadTab>
                        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Value="Remand" Text="Remand History" PageViewID="RemandsPage">
                        </telerik:RadTab>
                        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Value="Comments" Text="Docket Comments" PageViewID="DocketComments">
                        </telerik:RadTab>
                    </Tabs>
                </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="Multipage1" SelectedIndex="0" RenderSelectedPageOnly="false">
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="FullClaimPage" Width="460px">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pFullClaim" runat="server" Width="100%" />                                                         
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RemandsPage">
                        <asp:Panel ID="pRemandHistory" runat="server" Width="100%" />
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="DocketComments">
                        <asp:Panel ID="pDocketComments" runat="server" Width="100%" />
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                </telerik:RadMultiPage>
            </asp:Panel>
        </NestedViewTemplate>
        <GroupByExpressions>
            <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                <SelectFields>
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="-Docket_Status" FieldName="Docket_Status_Descr"
                        FormatString="{0:D}" HeaderValueSeparator=" : "></telerik:GridGroupByField>
                </SelectFields>
                <GroupByFields>
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Docket_Status_Descr" SortOrder="Descending">
                    </telerik:GridGroupByField>
                </GroupByFields>
            </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
        </GroupByExpressions>
        <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>
        <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
        </RowIndicatorColumn>
        <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"
                HeaderStyle-Width="25">
                <HeaderStyle Width="25px" />
                <ItemStyle CssClass="MyImageButton"></ItemStyle>
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="docket_id" UniqueName="docket_id" DataField="docket_id"
                Resizable="true" Visible="true" Display="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocketID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("docket_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAddDocketID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("docket_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEditDocketID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("docket_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="claimant_name" UniqueName="claimant_name"
                DataField="claimant_name" HeaderText="Claimant" Resizable="true" HeaderStyle-Width="125">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClaimant" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("claimant_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAddClaimant" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("claimant_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEditClaimant" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("claimant_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="125px" />
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Docket_Date" UniqueName="Docket_Date"
                DataField="Docket_Date" HeaderText="Docket Dt" Resizable="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocketDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Docket_Date", "{0:M/d/yyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpAddDocketDate" runat="server" Width="90">
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpEditDocketDate" runat="server" Width="90" DbSelectedDate='<%#Eval("Docket_Date") %>'>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="claim_num" UniqueName="claim_num" DataField="claim_num"
                HeaderText="JCN" Resizable="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblJCN" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("claim_num") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddJCN" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("claim_num") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCarrier" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Claim Number"
                        ControlToValidate="txtAddJCN" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditJCN" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("claim_num") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Docket_Comment" UniqueName="Docket_Comment"
                DataField="PTDRB_Comment" HeaderText="Docket Comment" Resizable="true" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDocketComment" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDocketComment" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Docket_Status" UniqueName="Docket_Status"
                DataField="Docket_Status_Descr" HeaderText="Docket Status" Resizable="true" DataType="System.String"
                HeaderStyle-Width="175">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocketStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Docket_Status_Descr") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboAddDocketStatus" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" DataTextField="Docket_Status_Descr"
                        AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Docket_Status_ID" runat="server" Width="250"
                        SelectionMode="Single" OnItemsRequested="cboAddDocketStatus_ItemsRequested">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboEditDocketStatus" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" DataTextField="Docket_Status_Descr"
                        AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Docket_Status_ID" Text='<%#Eval("Docket_Status_descr") %>'
                        runat="server" Width="250" SelectionMode="Single" DataCheckedField='<%#Eval("Docket_Status_id")  %>'
                        OnItemsRequested="cboAddDocketStatus_ItemsRequested">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="175px" />
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="accident_date" UniqueName="accident_date"
                DataField="accident_date" HeaderText="DOI" Resizable="true" ReadOnly="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInjuryDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("accident_date", "{0:M/d/yyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Claim_Admin" UniqueName="Claim_Admin"
                DataField="Claim_Admin" HeaderText="Claim Admin" Resizable="true" Visible="false"
                ReadOnly="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClaimAdmin" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Claim_Admin") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Carrier" UniqueName="Carrier" DataField="Carrier"
                HeaderText="Carrier" Resizable="true" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCarrier" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Carrier") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Self_Insured" UniqueName="Self_Insured"
                DataField="Self_Insured" HeaderText="Self Insured" Resizable="true" Visible="false"
                ReadOnly="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSelfInsured" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Self_Insured") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Payment_Received" UniqueName="Payment_Received"
                DataField="Payment_Received" HeaderText="Payment Received" Resizable="true" DataType="System.String"
                Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPaymentReceived" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Payment_Received_descr") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboAddPaymentReceived" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" DataTextField="Payment_Received"
                        AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Payment_Received" runat="server" Width="50"
                        SelectionMode="Single" OnItemsRequested="cboAddPaymentReceived_ItemsRequested">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboEditPaymentReceived" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" DataTextField="Payment_Received"
                        AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Payment_Received" Text='<%#Eval("Payment_Received_descr")  %>'
                        runat="server" Width="50" SelectionMode="Single" DataCheckedField='<%#Eval("Payment_Received")  %>'
                        OnItemsRequested="cboAddPaymentReceived_ItemsRequested">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Petition_Date" UniqueName="Petition_Date"
                DataField="Petition_Date" HeaderText="Petition Dt" Resizable="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPetitionDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Petition_Date", "{0:M/d/yyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpAddPetitionDate" runat="server" Width="90">
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpEditPetitionDate" runat="server" Width="90" DbSelectedDate='<%#Eval("Petition_Date") %>'>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Date_Received" UniqueName="Date_Received"
                DataField="Date_Received" HeaderText="Date Rec" Resizable="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateReceived" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date_Received", "{0:M/d/yyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpAddDateReceived" runat="server" Width="90">
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpEditDateReceived" runat="server" Width="90" DbSelectedDate='<%#Eval("Date_Received") %>'>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Remand" UniqueName="Remand" DataField="remanded_from_descr"
                HeaderText="Remanded From" Resizable="true" DataType="System.String" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRemand" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("remanded_from_descr") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboAddRemand" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" DataTextField="remanded_from_descr"
                        AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Remanded_From_ID" runat="server" Width="70"
                        SelectionMode="Single" OnItemsRequested="cboAddRemand_ItemsRequested">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboEditRemand" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" DataTextField="remanded_from_descr"
                        AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Remanded_From_ID" Text='<%#Eval("remanded_from_descr")  %>'
                        runat="server" Width="70" SelectionMode="Single" OnItemsRequested="cboAddRemand_ItemsRequested"
                        DataCheckedField='<%#Eval("Remand_From_ID")  %>'>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Remand_Date" UniqueName="Remand_Date"
                DataField="Remand_Date" HeaderText="Remand Date" Resizable="true" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRemandDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Remand_Date", "{0:M/d/yyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpAddRemandDate" runat="server" Width="90">
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpEditRemandDate" runat="server" Width="90" DbSelectedDate='<% #Eval("Remand_Date") %>'>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Remand_Comment" UniqueName="Remand_Comment"
                DataField="Remand_Comment" HeaderText="Remand Comment" Resizable="true" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRemandComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Remand_Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddRemandComment" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditRemandComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Remand_Comment") %>'
                        AccessKey='<%#Eval("remand_comment_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Settlement_Date" UniqueName="Settlement_Date"
                DataField="Settlement_Date" HeaderText="Settlement Date" Resizable="true" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSettlementDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Settlement_Date", "{0:M/d/yyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpAddSettlementDate" runat="server" Width="90">
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpEditSettlementDate" runat="server" Width="90" DbSelectedDate='<%#Eval("Settlement_Date") %>'>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Settlement_Comment" UniqueName="Settlement_Comment"
                DataField="Settlement_Comment" HeaderText="Settlement Comment" Resizable="true"
                Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSettlementComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Settlement_Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddSettlementComment" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditSettlementComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Settlement_Comment") %>'
                        AccessKey='<%#Eval("settlement_comment_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="DocketHistory" HeaderText="Docket">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnHistory" runat="server" Text="History" CommandName="DocketHistory" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings ColumnNumber="3" CaptionFormatString="Edit details for Admin Claim Num: {0}"
            CaptionDataField="claim_num">
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
            </EditColumn>
            <FormTableStyle GridLines="Horizontal" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="0" Height="110px">
            </FormTableStyle>
            <FormMainTableStyle GridLines="None" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%">
            </FormMainTableStyle>
            <FormCaptionStyle CssClass="EditFormHeader"></FormCaptionStyle>
            <FormTableItemStyle Wrap="False"></FormTableItemStyle>
            <FormTableAlternatingItemStyle Wrap="False"></FormTableAlternatingItemStyle>
            <FormTableButtonRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="EditFormButtonRow"></FormTableButtonRowStyle>
        </EditFormSettings>
        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings ReorderColumnsOnClient="True" AllowColumnsReorder="True" Selecting-AllowRowSelect="false">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
        <Resizing AllowRowResize="True" AllowColumnResize="True" EnableRealTimeResize="True"
            ResizeGridOnColumnResize="False"></Resizing>
    </ClientSettings>
    <GroupingSettings ShowUnGroupButton="false"></GroupingSettings>
    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
    </FilterMenu>
</telerik:RadGrid>
</asp:Panel>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
    public void LoadTabs(GridNestedViewItem viewitem)
    {
            //Find the first panel in the outer grid
            //Panel panel = ((GridNestedViewItem)item.ChildItem).FindControl("InnerContainer") as Panel;
            Panel panel = viewitem.FindControl("InnerContainer") as Panel;
            GridDataItem item = viewitem.ParentItem;

            if (panel != null)
            {

                //item.GetDataKeyValue("claim_num");
                //item.GetDataKeyValue("docket_id");

                //string s = item["docket_id"].ToString();

                ////Admin Claim Number
                //Label lblJCN = (Label)item["claim_num"].FindControl("lblJCN");

                //Label lblJCN = ((DataRowView)item.DataItem).Row["docket_id"].ToString();

                //string claim_num = ((DataRowView)item.DataItem).Row["claim_num"].ToString(); 

                string claim_num = item.GetDataKeyValue("claim_num").ToString();
                string docket_id = item.GetDataKeyValue("docket_id").ToString();

                //Docket ID
               // Label lblDocketID = (Label)item["docket_id"].FindControl("lblDocketID");

                //int docket_id = Convert.ToInt32(lblDocketID.Text);

                //string docket_id = ((DataRowView)item.DataItem).Row["docket_id"].ToString();

                Dictionary<string, string> paramValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                paramValues.Add("claim_num", claim_num);
                paramValues.Add("docket_id", docket_id.ToString());
                paramValues.Add("comment_type_id", "3");


                BaseUserControl ucFC = (BaseUserControl)LoadControl("UserControls\\UCFullClaim.ascx");
                Panel pFullClaim = Utility.FindControlRecursive(panel, "pFullClaim") as Panel;

                ucFC.ParamsValue = new Hashtable(paramValues);
                ucFC.LoadDataSet();
                pFullClaim.Controls.Add(ucFC);

                BaseUserControl ucRH = (BaseUserControl)LoadControl("UserControls\\UCRemandHistory.ascx");
                Panel pRemandHistory = Utility.FindControlRecursive(panel, "pRemandHistory") as Panel;


                ucRH.ParamsValue = new Hashtable(paramValues);
                ucRH.LoadDataSet();
                ucRH.ID = "ucRH";
                pRemandHistory.Controls.Add(ucRH);

                BaseUserControl ucDC = (BaseUserControl)LoadControl("UserControls\\UCComments.ascx");
                Panel pDocketComments = Utility.FindControlRecursive(panel, "pDocketComments") as Panel;

                ucDC.ParamsValue = new Hashtable(paramValues);
                ucDC.LoadDataSet();
                pDocketComments.Controls.Add(ucDC);
            }

        }



    protected void gdDocket_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridNestedViewItem)
        {
            LoadTabs(e.Item as GridNestedViewItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had to leave out a lot of the code behind due to space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found out my problem. I wasn't binding the datasource of my detailsview